# Custom SeekBar in Android, Only allow progression when touched at start

Tags: java, android, xml, seekbar

I'm trying to stop the progress of the seek bar unless the user started below progress(10), this ensures the user actually has to slide it, thus avoiding accidental activation. I've tried this so far and it looks like it'd work, however the slide bar can still be moved from anywhere (progress(0) up to progress(100).

```
sb.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        private Boolean isInRange = true;

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            if (seekBar.getProgress() > 95) {
                ((MainActivity)getActivity()).currentOrder = null;
                ((MainActivity)getActivity()).showMain();

            } else {
                seekBar.setProgress(0);
                isInRange = false;
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            if (seekBar.getProgress() < 10) {
                isInRange = true;
            } else {
                seekBar.setProgress(0);
                isInRange = false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            if(!isInRange) {
                seekBar.setProgress(0);
            }
        }

    });// Set on seek bar change listener
```

just in case you need it, here's the XML code of the seekbars container:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorFocus"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/seperator_bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_delivery_disabled"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:layout_margin="16dp">

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seek"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:max="100"
            android:progressDrawable="@android:color/transparent"
            android:thumb="@mipmap/ic_slide" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/delivered"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Large"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:id="@+id/textView" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'it'd work, however the slide bar can still be moved from anywhere'. Which part did work and which part didn't?

Comment: Basically, It's only supposed to slide if the user starts touching the slider below progress(10). at the moment that works, but if you then slide your finger then the slider comes over to where the touch is currently moving. I don't want it to move at all unless it's started within the boundaries set (< 10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `setProgress` is absolute value, not relative to where your progress currently is. What you actually are doing is essentially resetting the progress to 0 any time when the touch is not within the **first 10 percent** of the `SeekBar`, not within 10 percent of where the progress is. That, of course, is assuming that you can not provided `max` attribute, in which case the `max` value is set at 100.

So, you need to adjust your code to read current value, then compare it to current and see if it is within 10 percent. I would also recommend to keep track of starting position and end position rather then only having a simple `boolean` value to track it. Then you have to evaluate the value in relation to current position.

Comment: That makes sense, do you know what property I would get for the relative value?

Comment: @Zachary Looking through Android documentation, i don't think there is one. You'll have to calculate it based on current position and maxValue